# jquery click off function

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a search bar that will expand once clicked. When the user clicks elsewhere, the search bar will return to its normal state.

I haven't managed to do this, but have made it expand on click. Any help would be great

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({ "width": "200px"},400);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#search").on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({ "width": "200px"},400);
}); 

$(document).on('click', ':not(#search)', function(e){ 
    //when you click somewhere that is **not** search
    if(e.target.id !== 'search') {
        $("#search").animate({ "width": "50px"},400);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2W2z4/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(e){
       if( e.target.id == 'search' )
          {      
              $(e.target).animate({ "width": "200px"},400);
          }
       else
          { 
             $('#search').animate({ "width": "100px"},400);
          }

 });
```

Comment: Y U NOT USE `e.target` instead of `"#search"` (in the 1st part of the if statement)?

Comment: Because when you target outside search it animates that target, but i guess i could change the first animate to e.target

Comment: Hence I said "1st part of the if statement" :-P @anton

Comment: I think I am going to fix mine and "borrow" your `e.target.id` idea. I hope you don't mind ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Why bind it to the body and always have it attempting to animate the search box even when the user is not interacting with it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({ "width": "600px" }, 400);
    }).focusout(function () {
        $(this).animate({ "width": "400px" }, 400);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2W2z4/3/

Comment: hehe or even using `focus` and `blur` might do it! **`+1`**